# How to isolate servers from other machines connected to a single active directory?

Tags: active-directory

I have few machines connected to an Active Directory. In that, i want to isolate 3 servers (these 3 are distributed environment set up for testing purpose). I don't want other machines to connect with these 3 or share the resources assigned to these machines.

Comment: Define `connect` and define `share resources`.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft calls this "Server Isolation" and implements it using IPSec. 
http://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc770626(WS.10).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You'll need setup a firewall. Either using Windows' built-in advanced firewall (which IMO is not *that* advanced), or use a 3rd party firewall (I had good experience with **Outpost Firewall Pro**), or use a firewall appliance.

Comment: Can you go into some detail about what you find deficient in the Windows firewall?

Comment: IIRC, it's because with Windows' own firewall, deny rules always win against allow rules. So, it's impossible for me to block a subnet except some hosts within.

Comment: That's a good point; it's mostly correct. If you have an IPSec connection between the allowed hosts, that's an authenticated bypass rule and will override the block rule for the rest of the subnet. That's exactly how Server Isolation is intended to work, in the answer I provided.